# Triggering the spinner quantity button in Shopify

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify

I am trying to trigger the spinner quantity button in my Shopify store. Basically, I want to set a maximum limit order to 1. Below is code, I am trying to trigger the input with a class name "cart__qty-input".

I tried `$(".cart__qty-input:eq(0)").val(1).trigger('change');` but it is only changing the value not triggering the event.

```
<td class="cart__quantity-td text-right small--hide">
                <div class="cart__qty">
                  <label for="updates_large_34113200128045:3d569029201ce7fd4affe9f95f790cb6" class="cart__qty-label" data-quantity-label-desktop="">Quantity</label>
                  <input id="updates_large_34113200128045:3d569029201ce7fd4affe9f95f790cb6" class="cart__qty-input" type="number" name="updates[]" value="3" min="0" pattern="[0-9]*" data-quantity-input="" data-quantity-item="1" data-quantity-input-desktop="">
                </div>
                <div class="cart__qty-error-message-wrapper cart__qty-error-message-wrapper--desktop hide" role="alert" data-cart-quantity-error-message-wrapper="">
                  <span class="visually-hidden">Error </span>
                  <svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" role="presentation" class="icon icon-error" viewBox="0 0 14 14"><g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd"><path d="M7 0a7 7 0 0 1 7 7 7 7 0 1 1-7-7z"></path><path class="icon-error__symbol" d="M6.328 8.396l-.252-5.4h1.836l-.24 5.4H6.328zM6.04 10.16c0-.528.432-.972.96-.972s.972.444.972.972c0 .516-.444.96-.972.96a.97.97 0 0 1-.96-.96z"></path></g></svg>
                  <span class="cart__qty-error-message" data-cart-quantity-error-message=""></span>
                </div>
              </td>
```

Comment: "to trigger the spinner quantity button" - what? "but it is only changing the value not triggering the event" - what event?

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate your try to resolve this but why can't you 
set max limit of input rather than set value 1 
check this code

`$('input-class-name').attr('max',1);`

Comment: If they click Add to cart  button after they have done so already, the quantity will get incremented, this is why I want to update the value to 1, so no matter how many times they click the Add to Cart button, the value will stay to 1.